# Class of Interest in supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

The **positive class** in a binary classification problem, is usually the **class of interest** (e.g: *fraud*, *spam*, *cancer*).

Machine learning algorithms try to construct a classifier that can separate these two classes. Here, it does not matter what you call "*positive*" or "*1*" or "*true*"...

---

Are there examples for problems/algorithms where it is important to define something like a **class of interest** in supervised learning?